# unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally ChromeDriver Selenium Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь запустить `ChromeDriver` на `Ubuntu 16.04`. На винде всё ок.

Код код:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

                            options.addArguments("disable-setuid-sandbox");
                            options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
                            options.addArguments("allow-insecure-localhost");
                            if(WebRequest.isWindows()) {
                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", UTILS.getRoot() + SEPARATOR + CHROME_WINDOWS_PATH);
                                options.setBinary(UTILS.getRoot() + SEPARATOR + CHROME_WINDOWS_PATH);
                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "D:\\chromedriver.log");
                                //options.addArguments("--log-path=D:\\chromedriver.log");
                            } else if(WebRequest.isUnix()) {
                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", UTILS.getRoot() + SEPARATOR + CHROME_LINUX_PATH);
                                options.setBinary(UTILS.getRoot() + SEPARATOR + CHROME_LINUX_PATH);
                                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "/var/www/www-root/data/screenshot/chromedriver.log");
                            }
                            LoggingPreferences preferences = new LoggingPreferences();
                            preferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.OFF);
                            preferences.enable(LogType.CLIENT, Level.OFF);
                            preferences.enable(LogType.DRIVER, Level.OFF);
                            preferences.enable(LogType.PERFORMANCE, Level.OFF);
                            preferences.enable(LogType.SERVER, Level.OFF);
                            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, preferences);
                            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.verbose", true);
                            capabilities.setCapability("networkConnectionEnabled", true);
                            capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
                            capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
                            capabilities.setCapability("--user-agent", USER_AGENT);
                            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
                            options.addArguments("--user-agent="+USER_AGENT);
                           capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                            DRIVER = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Но при старте возникает ошибка:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8) on port 26570
Only local connections are allowed.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-87-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.07 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'linkruiter', ip: '91.234.34.93', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-87-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
    at com.linkedin.model.UserModel.AccountLinkedin(UserModel.java:362)
    at com.linkedin.model.UserModel.Execute(UserModel.java:146)
    at com.linkedin.controller.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at com.linkedin.Server.doPost(Server.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.linkedin.filter.Main.doFilter(Main.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Сам хром установлен на Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по стэктрэйсу сессия не поднялась. Дальше нативка упала.

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
```

A судя по строке Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally, либо драйвер до хрома вообще не достучался, либо не смог стартонуть за недостаточностью прав, но скорее всего сам хром стартонул но драйвер не смог к нему приконектиться. Если падает практически сразу, то скорее всего версия хрома с драйвером не совместима.
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com Тут взять последнюю версию драйвера
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb Тут лежит стабильная версия хрома

Если это не решит проблему, то тогда нужно смотреть в сторону сети так как явно падает на createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365